# compare two PowerShell arrays only if they both contain values

Tags: powershell

In the following PowerShell code, functions `hour00_numbers` and `hour01_numbers` create two arrays, that contain numbers matching a specific regex.

```
function hour00_numbers {
    foreach ($event in $filter00) {
        $hour00Numbers = @()
        $hour00Numbers += [regex]::Matches($event.Source.Summary -replace ' ', '9 *[45679]( *[0-9]){6}').Value
        $hour00Numbers
    }
}
    
function hour01_numbers {
    foreach ($event in $filter01) {
        $hour01Numbers = @()
        $hour01Numbers += [regex]::Matches($event.Source.Summary -replace ' ', '9 *[45679]( *[0-9]){6}').Value
        $hour01Numbers
    }
}
```

I then check if both arrays are not empty, and if they are not, I check to see if they contain matching numbers.

```
function matching_numbers01 {
    if ($null -ne $(hour00_numbers) -and $null -ne $(hour01_numbers)) {
        $script:matchingNumbers01 = Compare-Object $(hour00_numbers) $(hour01_numbers) -IncludeEqual | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '==' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
    }
    else {
        $matchingNumbers01 = $null
    }

    if ($null -ne $(hour00_numbers)) {
        Write-Host "hour00 numbers: $(hour00_numbers)" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "hour00 is empty" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }

    if ($null -ne $(hour01_numbers)) {
        Write-Host "hour01 numbers: $(hour01_numbers)" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "hour01 is empty" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }

    if ($null -ne $matchingNumbers01) {
        Write-Host "matching numbers are: $matchingNumbers01" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "no matching numbers found" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
```

I'm doing something wrong here though, because I will frequently get a message saying

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ReferenceObject' because it is null
```

If either of the two arrays is empty, it shouldn't compare anything. It should only compare the arrays if both are not empty.

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: You’re calling your ```hours00_numbers```multiple times in your ```matching_numbers01``` - is there a reason you’re not assigning it to a variable instead and using that? At the moment you’ve got a race condition where the result could change half way through your script which means your ```if``` expression evaluates to ```$true``` but is actually ```$false``` by the time you call ```compare-object``` on the next line. Also, is there a reason you don’t pass the vaulted in as parameters? It makes it much easier to reason about (and debug) a program that only acts on local variables…

Comment: Your tests fail, because an empty array is different from `$null`. Even if empty, it is a valid, non-NULL object. To test for both non-NULL and non-emptiness, simply use the array in a boolean context, e. g. `if( $myarray ) {'not empty'} else {'empty or null'}`.

Comment: As an aside, try to avoid explicit array creation and addition in PowerShell, which is inefficient in terms of performance and amount of code you have to write. E. g. the first loop could be rewritten like this, while behaving identically: `foreach ($event in $filter00) { [regex]::Matches($event.Source.Summary -replace ' ', '9 *[45679]( *[0-9]){6}').Value }`

Comment: I'd suggest using $hour00Numbers = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList instead of $hour00Numbers = @() and then use $hour00Numbers.count to figure out if it is empty.

Comment: @zett42 Agree it's often not needed, but not declaring an array can in some situations cause issues where you don't know if you'll have one or multiple results, as you can end up with a variable that can be different data types (for instance `PSCustomObject` vs `Object[]`, which depending what you're doing with it later can cause issues if later commands handle the two differently.

Comment: @KeithLangmead, in that case you use the [Array subexpression operator `@( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#array-subexpression-operator--) where *the result is always an array of 0 or more objects.*, like: `@(foreach ($event in $filter00) { ... })` and if you want to prevent it from unrolling when being output from a function, you might want to use the [Comma operator `,`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#comma-operator-), like: `function MyF { ,@( foreach ... ) }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the problem you've reported, your code has a few other issues:

- Use of global variables to pass values into (and out of) functions - e.g. `$filter00`, `$filter01` and `$matchingNumbers01`. It's hard to reason about these in isolation because they depend on program state that exists outside their scope.
- Duplication of code as a result - e.g. the **functions** `hour00_numbers` and `hour01_numbers` are identical except for which global variable they reference - this makes maintenance harder.
- Performance issues / race condition by repeatedly calling the `hour00_numbers` and `hour01_numbers` functions inside `matching_numbers01` instead of caching the results into internal variables.

So, here's a refactor that uses function parameters and output streams to address these problems. It also uses some of the feedback in the comments, and it might just accidentally fix your root problem as a side-effect as well...

```
# define a function to filter the events, give it a meaningful name, and pass
# the raw event list as a parameter so we only need one version of the function
function Get-HourEvents {
    param( $Events )
    foreach($event in $Events) {
        [regex]::Matches($event.Source.Summary -replace ' ', '9 *[45679]( *[0-9]){6}').Value
    }
}

# pass the filtered events in as parameters '$Left' and '$Right',
# and return the results in the output stream so we don't need to
# read global variables. this makes it easier to reason about, and
# a lot easier to test with frameworks like pester
function Get-MatchingEvents {
    param( $Left, $Right )

    if ($null -eq $Left) {
        Write-Host "Left is empty" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Left numbers: $Left" -ForegroundColor Green
    }

    if ($null -eq $Right) {
        Write-Host "Right is empty" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "hour01 numbers: $Right" -ForegroundColor Green
    }

    if (($null -eq $Left) -or ($null -eq $Right) {
        $results = $null
    }
    else {
        $results = Compare-Object $Left $Right -IncludeEqual | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '==' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
    }

    if ($null -eq $results) {
        Write-Host "no matching numbers found" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "matching numbers are: $results" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $results
    }

}

# use the functions like this:

# get the filtered event lists
$hour00Events = Get-HourEvents -Events $filter00
$hour01Events = Get-HourEvents -Events $filter01

# match the event lists and assign the result to a variable
$matchingNumbers01 = Get-MatchingEvents -Left $hour00Events -Right $hour01Events
```

I also took the liberty of inverting some of your `if( ... -ne ... ) { ... } else { ... }` as I find it easier to think about when the `else` will trigger if the `if` uses a "positive" expression otherwise the `else` condition becomes a double-negative, but that's just personal style - ymmv.

If you're still seeing the same issue with this version of your code feel free to post a comment below...